# how to use define_extern in Halide with JIT？

Tags: halide

when i compile the "extern_stage.cpp" in Halide/test/correctness/extern_stage.cpp, cmd as follow:
g++ extern_stage.cpp -g -I ../../../Halide/build/include/ -L ../../../Halide/bin -lHalide -lpthread -ldl -o lesson_01 -std=c++11
it is compiled successfully,but when i run it ,i got a error such as:
"HalideJITMemoryManager: unable to find address for flip_x"

i think the filp_x is "extern c" , and the symbol as follow:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7edVr.png)
but why it could not run？

Comment: Do not post images of code or terminal output. Instead, copy them into code blocks in your question.

Answer (score 0):

You need to compile with `-rdynamic` so that the executable's symbols are exported such that they can be found by name at runtime.

This is available in CMake generically through the `ENABLE_EXPORTS` target property. See: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/ENABLE_EXPORTS.html